# How would I go about showcasing my skills in Math Stack Exchange on LinkedIn or on Resume?

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics, cv

How would I be able to showcase my mathematical prowess on a LinkedIn profile or even on a resume/CV?

I am only wondering because I have many up voted answers and would like to demonstrate to a future employer or graduate program. Any advice or tips would be helpful. I was wondering about employer because I know there is Teams on StackExchange and was wondering if Q&A sites are popular in the workplace environment.

Comment: Are you participating in MSE under your real name or an alias? If you want any credit, you better use your real name.

Comment: I can change it to my real name. I just did it.

Comment: Also: I looked at your MSE answers and questions. As a member of a PhD-grogram (in math) admissions committee, I would not be impressed, since it mostly  shows proficiency at the calculus level. Nothing at the "upper division math" level (abstract algebra, real analysis, etc.). Sorry to break it to you.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike How about tutoring and teaching assistant roles?

Comment: I actually wanted to say that if you are to be partially supported by a TAship, then MSE participation is a useful information. However, it will be only of marginal help since the main factor in admission is the probability of success in research.

Comment: Related question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/190539/).

Comment: *knows how to use Google* isn't something you put.

Comment: @Mazura It is not so much knows how to use Google its that its the ability to use LaTex to communicate mathematical problems and communicate problems in a Q&A style environment. As well as knowing math.

Comment: @Mazura I'd argue that is a remarkable activity, and vast majority of people I've met in real life lack it. There are many levels to knowing how to google IMO

Comment: Related, in a different discipline: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/chemistry-se-on-your-cv-r%c3%a9sum%c3%a9-other-professional-avenues/4875#4875

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a US centric answer, but it may apply more widely.

Anything positive you do can be put on a CV, but emphasize more important things and relegate things like this to an "Other" section. They would only be a factor in a graduate school application process in a very minor and marginal way. Your coursework and letters of recommendation are much more important.

But, yes, mention somewhere that you tutor other folk and/or have been awarded a TA position, especially if merit is part of the reason you were give it.

As for Stack Exchange participation, I suggest that you say no more than "Frequent contributor to Math Stack exchange" with a link to the site.

And treat the CV as a living document, pushing lesser things off as more important things are added (published papers, especially).

I have nothing to say about LinkedIn as I don't use it and would be unlikely to visit it as part of a student's application.

Comment: Are you sure? I've been reached out several times over my StackExchange merits. Academic merits aren't the end-of-all and more people are realizing it. But really, academic merits are comically overrated. 4.0 in Stanford doesn't guarantee you're smart or useful.